# Convert pdf to rtf or doc

Tags: java, pdf, rtf, doc, document-conversion

It is possible to convert a pdf document to rtf or doc using java?

Comment: [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128733/convert-pdf-to-rtf-in-java) has been asked previously

Comment: See this thread: [Convert PDF to Word in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090154/convert-pdf-to-word-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can use free [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/index.php?q=project/jasperreports) library or shareware [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) products.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more detailed how can I use Jasper Reports for a conversion operation?

Comment: You can use this library to read pdf file in some data structure in memory and then using the same library to create a rtf file from this data structure.